# Regular Expression to replace word from String

Tags: java

All i have to replace dynamically even i don't know which string would be arrive between this two % sign also replaced value is dynamically arrived.

for Example :

```
this is %XXXX%
```

now i want to replace word between two percent sign like

```
this is tttt
```

Please suggest which regular expr i have to use for same

Comment: are the vakue for %animal%, %bird% defined.. or you pass them at run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String s[] = {"this is %animal%", "this is %bird%"};
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    s[i].replaceAll("%animal%", "cow");
    s[i].replaceAll("%bird%", "dove");
    System.out.println(s[i]);
}
```

Edit: Oh i see you changed the question. I assume you mean you do not know beforehand what will be between the %%. Try the following:

```
public static String replacePercentage(String oldString, String replacement) {
    int Percent = oldString.indexOf('%');
    if (Percent == -1) {
        return oldString;
    }
    int Percent2 = oldString.indexOf('%', Percent + 1);
    if (Percent2 == -1) {
        return oldString;
    }
    String newString = oldString.substring(0, Percent);
    newString += replacement; 
    newString += oldString.substring(Percent2 + 1);        
    return replacePercentage(newString, replacement);
}
```

If you do know what word will be between the %%, use `oldString.replaceAll("%"+ search +"%", replacement)` instead.

Edit2: Recursion are much more fun. Return `newString` directly on line 13 if you are sure there is only one %% word per string.

Edit3:
With regex:

```
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("%[^%]*%"); 
public static String replacePercentageRegex(String oldString, String replacement) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(oldString);
    return  matcher.replaceAll(replacement);
}
```

I'm unsure about performance on the regex version.

Comment: Thanks it works...is there any regular Exp do you know for replace same ??

Comment: Yeah, it can be done with regex, but i doubt it will give any form of advantage other then that it's easier to change later on.
See http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util.regex/an-example-of-regular-expression-search-and-replace-pr.html
You would need a patern like "%[^%]*%".

Comment: For the record: Regex is about 2-4x as slow. Not all that bad.

Comment: I just discovered `oldString.replaceAll("%[^%]*%", replacement);`. This doesn't catch the pattern and is probably a notch slower again.

Answer (score 2):

Any specific reason you want to use regular expression. You can use `String` function `replaceAll` to replace the words with desired one.

Comment: word is not specific it may be any...but just containing between %%.

Comment: Use Java patterns then http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html. The example is given in documentation itself.

Comment: So if you want to replace `%animal%` to `cow`, having for input only `animal` and `cow`, you are able to do this str.replaceAll("%"+param1+"%", param2);

Answer (score 0):

Don't even need `replaceAll(regex, replacement)`, which takes a regex... just use `replace(old, replacement)`, which takes plain strings.